# looking for html prototype kit

Tags: html, interface

I'm looking for a fast way to prototype simple html sites. A collection of pre made html elements (like buttons, forms, messagebox's,... )

I found something like it once, but forgot to bookmark and have been searching for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) may be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a template. Just search for "[template website](http://www.google.com/search?q=template%20website)" on Google and you'll find a tonne of website offering both free and paid templates.